# What is the best way to stop Drupal textfield ahah event from disabling field while processing?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

I have a simple Drupal form in a custom module where exiting a `textfield` should retrieve some information about the entered text via `ahah` to populate a `div`.

This works fine, except if the user quickly submits the form while the textfield's ahah event is being processed.

It looks like while the ahah event is being processed the textfield is disabled, which of course means it's value is not submitted. This means validation fails as the textfield is a required field, so the user is returned to the form with an appropriate error. The textfield is always empty when this happens.

If the user waits for the event to finish, the textfield returns to being enabled and submitting works as expected, as does submitting by using the enter key while in the textfield (the event doesn't fire then, so the textfield isn't disabled while it retrieves data).

Is there a way to disable the disabling of the textfield while it's ahah event is being processed, or some other workaround?

Example of the textfield:

```
$form['id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Crop No.'),
    '#default_value' => $crop['id'] ? $crop['id'] : '',
    '#size' => 6,
    '#disabled' => $disabled,
    '#ahah' => array(
        'path' => 'spcs-myspuds/yields/js/crop/description/' . $crop_idx,
        'wrapper' => 'spcs-myspuds-yields-edit-crop-description-row-' . $crop_idx,
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'none',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.

I had to override `Drupal.ahah.prototype.beforeSubmit`, the function that disables the input before the submit (well, duh!).

I included the following JavaScript in my module (using `drupal_add_js`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (typeof beforeSubmitOverride == 'undefined' || beforeSubmitOverride == false) {
    Drupal.ahah.prototype.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
      // Disable the element that received the change.
      // IMiJ: Unless it's a text input, otherwise we could submit while element is diabled and loose data.
      if ($(this.element).attr('type') != 'text') {
        $(this.element).addClass('progress-disabled').attr('disabled', true);
      }

      // Insert progressbar or throbber.
      if (this.progress.type == 'bar') {
        var progressBar = new Drupal.progressBar('ahah-progress-' + this.element.id, eval(this.progress.update_callback), this.progress.method, eval(this.progress.error_callback));
        if (this.progress.message) {
          progressBar.setProgress(-1, this.progress.message);
        }
        if (this.progress.url) {
          progressBar.startMonitoring(this.progress.url, this.progress.interval || 1500);
        }
        this.progress.element = $(progressBar.element).addClass('ahah-progress ahah-progress-bar');
        this.progress.object = progressBar;
        $(this.element).after(this.progress.element);
      }
      else if (this.progress.type == 'throbber') {
        this.progress.element = $('<div class="ahah-progress ahah-progress-throbber"><div class="throbber">&nbsp;</div></div>');
        if (this.progress.message) {
          $('.throbber', this.progress.element).after('<div class="message">' + this.progress.message + '</div>');
        }
        $(this.element).after(this.progress.element);
      }
    };
  };
  beforeSubmitOverride = true;
});
```

This is a copy of `Drupal.ahah.prototype.beforeSubmit` as defined in misc/ahah.js with one small change, wrapping the disabling of the input with an if statement to make sure we don't disable text fields.

This is wrapped in a few lines to ensure the re-defining of the prototype happens just once after the DOM is ready.

It might be better to only stop the disabling of the input if a setting is passed such as "disable" => false, but the above worked for the one case in the one page for the one custom module I needed this fix.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the #required property TRUE of the textfield to make it a required field.Please set the #disabled property FALSE to check whether it is not occurred due to this.Please remember that #ahah event will call the validate function  when it is being processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Naveen, but the references to the #required and #disabled parameters are irrelevant in this case (and #disabled is false in the test scenarios anyway otherwise data couldn't be input that triggers the ahah event). The problem is a an issue with the ahah disabling the input while it processes, and the ahah event does not do any validation or trigger any validation hooks.